# Azure DevOps pipeline DotNetCore test path projects pattern

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm trying to test my .NET Core 5.0 projects in my Azure DevOps pipeline. When using a full path to one of my test projects the pipeline will test that single project. When using a pattern to search for all my test projects he can't find one of them.

My project structure is as follows:

1. backend

   1. DemoProject (with the .sln file)

      1. DemoProject.Application
      2. DemoProject.Application.Test
      3. DemoProject.Persistance
      4. DemoProject.Persistance.Test
   2. DemoProject 2

      1. ....

To find a solution I created a simple version of my pipeline template:

```
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: './backend/DemoProject/DemoProject.Application.Tests/DemoProject.Application.Tests.csproj'
```

When using the full path (`./backend/DemoProject/DemoProject.Application.Tests/DemoProject.Application.Tests.csproj`), the pipeline find's the selected project. When using a pattern (`./backend/DemoProject/\*\*/\*.Tests.csproj` or `./backend/DemoProject/\*\*/DemoProject.Application.Tests.csproj`), the pipeline can't find any project.

Does someone knows what the correct pattern is to run all my test projects inside the DemoProject folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `**/*.Test.csproj`, I have used it in projects with more complex folder structures without any issues.

```yaml
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: test
        arguments: --configuration Release
        projects: '**/*.Test.csproj'
        workingDirectory: './backend/DemoProject/'
```

Comment: Besides my demo project I have a second project inside the backend folder. That project I want to test and release separate. With the pattern you suggested both projects will be tested.

Comment: Could you combine it with [`WorkingDirectory` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devopst) in your task?

Comment: The combination of the pattern and the WorkingDirectory argument was the solution, thank you!

Comment: Its an absolute working solution. Worked like charm on a more complex folder structure to run all tests.